# Lost translateY(-3px) after adding JS (appearOnScroll)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Essentially what I'm trying to do is set a transition delay for the CTA button to fade in from the bottom when the user visits the landing page. I had to use this because I was using @keyframes and it was causing the text inside the button to be jumping around slightly when the button was hovered, it just didn't look good so I found this solution but now my button effects no longer work as expected.

It's supposed to translateY(-3px) on hover & translateY(1px) when clicked. After adding the JS (appearOnScroll) features it no longer moves upwards. Also my transition effects are back to default and no longer applied as well, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const faders = document.querySelectorAll(".fade--in");

const appearOptions = {
  threshold: 1,
  rootMargin: "-200px 0px -300px 0px",
};

const appearOnScroll = new IntersectionObserver(function (
  enteries,
  appearOnScroll
) {
  enteries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      return;
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.add("appear");
      appearOnScroll.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  });
},
appearOptions);

faders.forEach((fader) => {
  appearOnScroll.observe(fader);
});
```

```css
html {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #2e2e2e;
  font-family: Arial;
}

span {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn-container {
  margin-top: 6.5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.heading-primary--main {
  font-size: 120px;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 0.313rem 0.625rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn--white {
  background: white;
  color: grey;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.fade--in {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.fade--in.appear {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 1s ease, opacity 1.5s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Fade in Bottom</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      
      <div class="header__hero-text">
        <h1 class="heading-primary">
          <span class="heading-primary--main">Button</span>
          <span class="heading-primary--sub"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</span>
        </h1>
          <span class="btn-container">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn--white fade--in">Button</a></span>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will work if you apply the ```:hover``` on the element that has those new classes added ```.btn.fade--in.appear:hover```, but since you have set some delay, you need to modify that.

Comment: @prettyInPink I tried that but maybe I'm not understanding something, can you clarify what you mean by "but since you have set some delay, you need to modify that."

I added the :hover to the .btn.fade--in.appear:hover as you mentioned and its not working. Can you show me what you mean with an example?

Comment: Not working for you?

Comment: I just checked it, looks like when I run the snippet the button appears to "click" downwards but its extremely slow. Also as far as the transition delay, I will want that to appear a little bit later after the text, anyway to work around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a specificity issue. What fixed it is moving the **.fade--in** class from the anchor tag and moving it to the span **.btn-container** element. I've added the updated code in a snippet to this answer. Thank you @prettyInPink for pointing me in the right direction, much appreciated.

```js
const faders = document.querySelectorAll(".fade--in");

const appearOptions = {
  threshold: 1,
  rootMargin: "-200px 0px -300px 0px",
};

const appearOnScroll = new IntersectionObserver(function (
  enteries,
  appearOnScroll
) {
  enteries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      return;
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.add("appear");
      appearOnScroll.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  });
},
appearOptions);

faders.forEach((fader) => {
  appearOnScroll.observe(fader);
});
```

```css
html {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #2e2e2e;
  font-family: Arial;
}

span {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn-container {
  margin-top: 6.5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.heading-primary--main {
  font-size: 120px;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 0.313rem 0.625rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn--white {
  background: white;
  color: grey;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.fade--in {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.fade--in.appear {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 1s ease, opacity 1.5s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Fade in Bottom</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      
      <div class="header__hero-text">
        <h1 class="heading-primary">
          <span class="heading-primary--main">Button</span>
          <span class="heading-primary--sub"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</span>
        </h1>
          <span class="btn-container fade--in">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn--white">Button</a></span>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, as requested above, simply changed the class and set the `transition-delay` to `0s`.

```
.btn.fade--in.appear:hover {
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    box-shadow: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.btn.fade--in.appear:active {
    transform: translateY(-1px);
    box-shadow: 0 0.313rem 0.625rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```js
const faders = document.querySelectorAll(".fade--in");

const appearOptions = {
  threshold: 1,
  rootMargin: "-200px 0px -300px 0px",
};

const appearOnScroll = new IntersectionObserver(function (
  enteries,
  appearOnScroll
) {
  enteries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      return;
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.add("appear");
      appearOnScroll.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  });
},
appearOptions);

faders.forEach((fader) => {
  appearOnScroll.observe(fader);
});
```

```css
html {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #2e2e2e;
  font-family: Arial;
}

span {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn-container {
  margin-top: 6.5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.heading-primary--main {
  font-size: 120px;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
}

.btn.fade--in.appear:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.btn.fade--in.appear:active {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 0.313rem 0.625rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.btn--white {
  background: white;
  color: grey;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.fade--in {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.fade--in.appear {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 1s ease, opacity 1.5s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Fade in Bottom</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      
      <div class="header__hero-text">
        <h1 class="heading-primary">
          <span class="heading-primary--main">Button</span>
          <span class="heading-primary--sub"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</span>
        </h1>
          <span class="btn-container">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn--white fade--in">Button</a></span>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```